# Como fazer um processo esperar pelos 'irmãos'

Tags: c, processo, unix

Olá. Preciso criar uma árvore de processos, até o momento o que eu consegui fazer foi criar um lado da árvore, matar tudo e depois criar o outro lado.
Mas preciso criar toda a árvore antes e começar a matar os filhos e o pai.

Meu código que cria um lado -> mata tudo -> cria o outro -> mata tudo -> mata pai. Já tentei usar `wait()`, `waitpid()` e não consigo fazer o P4 esperar o P5 e ambos esperarem o P6 e P7

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    clock_t t;
    double time_taken;
    t = clock();
    int status;
    pid_t idProcesso; // P1
    printf("I'm P1: %d  |  my dad: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    idProcesso = fork();    

    switch(idProcesso){
        case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
        case 0: //P2
            printf("I'm P2: %d  |  my dad P1: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());          
            idProcesso = fork();
            switch(idProcesso){
                case -1: exit(-1); //Error
                case 0: //P4
                    printf("I'm P4: %d  |  my dad P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    break;

                default: //Continue P2
                wait(&status);
                printf("I'm P2: %d  |  Already waited for my son P4: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
                idProcesso = fork(); //P5
                switch(idProcesso){
                    case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                    case 0: //P5
                        printf("I'm P5: %d  |  my dad P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                        break;
                    default: //Continue P5
                        wait(&status); //P2 waits his son P5
                        printf("I'm P2: %d  |  Already waited for my son P5: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
                        break;

                }
            }
        break;
        default: //Continue P1          
            wait(&status);
            printf("I'm P1: %d  |  Already waited for my son P2: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
            idProcesso = fork(); //P1 creates son
            switch(idProcesso){
                case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                case 0://P3
                    printf("I'm P3: %d  |  my dad P1: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    idProcesso = fork(); //P3 creates son P6
                    switch(idProcesso){
                        case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                        case 0: //P6 son of P3
                            printf("I'm P6: %d  |  my dad P3: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                            break;
                        default: //Continue P3
                            wait(&status); //P3 waits his son P6
                            printf("I'm P3: %d  | Already waited for my son P6: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
                            idProcesso = fork(); //P3 creates son P7
                            switch(idProcesso){
                                case -1: exit(-1);//ERROR
                                case 0: //P7 son of P3
                                    printf("I'm P7: %d  |  son of P3: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                    break;
                                default: //P3 waits son P7
                                    wait(&status);
                                    printf("I'm P3: %d  |  Already waited for my son P7: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;                  
                default: //Continue P1              
                    wait(&status); // P1 waits his son P3
                    printf("I'm P1 again, my id: %d\n", getpid());
                    t = clock() - t;
                    time_taken = ( (double)t ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                    printf("Time used in seconds: %f\n", time_taken);
            }
            break;
    } //SWITCH
} //Main
```

O que preciso fazer:

[image: O que preciso fazer:]

Comment: qual a sua dificuldade?

Comment: @pmargreff Não consigo criar os 2 lados ao mesmo tempo. Só consigo criar um lado -> esse lado morre -> só então crio o outro lado. Preciso criar todos os processos e só depois matar eles.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está colocando os comandos de `wait()` antes dos comandos de `fork()` que criam os próximos processos. Por exemplo, em P2, antes de executar o `wait()` que espera P4 você deve executar o `fork()` que cria P5. Da mesma forma, em P1, antes de executar o `wait()` que espera P2 você deve executar o `fork()` que cria P3.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    clock_t t;
    double time_taken;
    t = clock();
    int status;
    pid_t idProcesso; // P1
    pid_t idChild; // Aby child process
    printf("I'm P1: %d  |  my dad: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    idProcesso = fork();    

    switch(idProcesso){
        case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
        case 0: //P2
            printf("I'm P2: %d  |  my dad P1: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());          
            idProcesso = fork();
            switch(idProcesso){
                case -1: exit(-1); //Error
                case 0: //P4
                    printf("I'm P4: %d  |  my dad P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    sleep(5);
                    break;

                default: //Continue P2
                idProcesso = fork(); //P5
                switch(idProcesso){
                    case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                    case 0: //P5
                        printf("I'm P5: %d  |  my dad P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                        sleep(5);
                        break;
                    default: //Continue P5
                        idChild = wait(&status);
                        printf("I'm P2: %d  |  Already waited for my son: %d\n", getpid(), idChild);
                        idChild = wait(&status); //P2 waits his son P5
                        printf("I'm P2: %d  |  Already waited for my son: %d\n", getpid(), idChild);
                        break;

                }
            }
        break;
        default: //Continue P1
            idProcesso = fork(); //P1 creates son
            switch(idProcesso){
                case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                case 0://P3
                    printf("I'm P3: %d  |  my dad P1: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    idProcesso = fork(); //P3 creates son P6
                    switch(idProcesso){
                        case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                        case 0: //P6 son of P3
                            printf("I'm P6: %d  |  my dad P3: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                            sleep(5);
                            break;
                        default: //Continue P3
                            idProcesso = fork(); //P3 creates son P7
                            switch(idProcesso){
                                case -1: exit(-1);//ERROR
                                case 0: //P7 son of P3
                                    printf("I'm P7: %d  |  son of P3: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                    sleep(5);
                                    break;
                                default: //P3 waits son P7
                                    idChild = wait(&status); //P3 waits his son P6
                                    printf("I'm P3: %d  | Already waited for my son: %d\n", getpid(), idChild);
                                    idChild = wait(&status);
                                    printf("I'm P3: %d  |  Already waited for my son: %d\n", getpid(), idChild);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;                  
                default: //Continue P1
                    idChild = wait(&status);
                    printf("I'm P1: %d  |  Already waited for my son: %d\n", getpid(), idChild);
                    idChild = wait(&status); // P1 waits his son P3
                    printf("I'm P1: %d  |  Already waited for my son: %d\n", getpid(), idChild);
                    printf("I'm P1 again, my id: %d\n", getpid());
                    t = clock() - t;
                    time_taken = ( (double)t ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                    printf("Time used in seconds: %f\n", time_taken);
            }
            break;
    } //SWITCH
} //Main
```

Note que essa solução garante que **nenhum processo esperará que outro termine para ser criado**. No entanto, ela não garante que a árvore inteira seja criada antes que os processos terminem. Se o processo P4, por exemplo, terminar muito rápido, pode ser que não tenha dado tempo do processo P7 ter sido criado ainda.

Para ilustrar um caso mais realista, em que os processos das folhas realizam uma operação mais demorada do que um simples `break()`, eu introduzi o `sleep(5)` ao fim de cada processo. Se você eliminá-lo, poderá observar casos em que alguns processos terminem antes que outros tenham sido criados.